# JMH add memory using Options builder

Tags: java, jmh

I am running a JMH benchmark:

```
         Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .output("C:/test/infinispan/benchmarkThr" + THREAD_COUNT + ".txt")
                .include(InfinispanFileStoreCreateUpdateGetBenchmark.class.getSimpleName())
                .include(InfinispanMemoryCreateUpdateGetBenchmark.class.getSimpleName())
                //.jvmArgsPrepend("-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m")
                .warmupIterations(0)
                .measurementIterations(INTERATIONS)
                .timeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .mode(Mode.SingleShotTime)
                .threads(THREAD_COUNT)
                .forks(1)
                .build();

        new Runner(opt).run();
```

I get OutOfMemoryError. I wanted to add more (the commented out text) but I iget an error that seems strange to me (this should IMO work):

```
# Run progress: 0,00% complete, ETA 00:16:40
# Fork: 1 of 1
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms1024M -Xmx1124M
```

How to succesfully add the memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide each argument separately using 2 `String` instead of one as next:

```
...
.jvmArgs("-Xms1024m", "-Xmx1024m")
...
```